# Why can't I connect to this switch ther the comm port?

Tags: switch, serial

I have an enterasys C2G124-48 switch that I need to set up some port mirroring on to troubleshoot some Voip issues.  However I am having issues connecting to the switch through putty.

I am following the instructions in the manual here:

http://www.manualslib.com/manual/236620/Enterasys-Securestack-C2-C2g124-48p.html?page=49

And I have ensured that the com port is set up as follows in putty:

Speed: 9600
Data Bits: 8
Stop Bits: 1
Parity: None
Flow Control: XON/XOFF

Putty initiates the connection, but nothing appears on the terminal and no input is accepted.

I have restarted the switch without any results.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: 1) are you sure that the console port is enabled? 2) why not connect over telnet or ssh?

Comment: The switch was purchased used, and did not get a ip from dhcp, the only way I know to determine the ip is to connect to the console port.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated.  @EEAA

Comment: You might need a null-modem cable.

Comment: @TomO'Connor  the manual states a db9 cable.

Comment: db9 specifies the end connectors of the cable. Null modem specifies what pinout it uses. Agreed with Tom, you need a null modem cable.

Comment: Once you do get control of the switch, I'd highly recommend giving it a static IP address, turning off telnet, and enabling ssh so you can access it remotely, without needing to connect a console cable.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with:

```
1 Null Modem DB9 Serial Cable +
1 USB Serial DB9 Adapter +
Putty 
   (9600 baud (x690 & x870 require 115200)
   no parity
   8 data bits
   1 stop bit
   XON/XOFF flow control) +
```

Switch Enterasys B2H124-48

I didn't get the welcome screen as said in the manual, but after type 'admin' and press 'enter' the prompt showed waiting for commands... : )

Good luck!